# Is k-means parallelizable (other than the data parallelism of the distance function computation)

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, data-mining, cluster

The k-means algorithm is known to be NP-hard.

While the distance function computation in the algorithm loop is data parallel, the algorithm is iterative and may become exponential in the number of iterations.

Is there a way to parallelize in practice k-means so as to alleviate (even in a small way) the hardness of k-means?

Comment: What do you mean by "alleviate the hardness of k-means"?  K-means is already typically pretty efficient on real data in practice, even disregarding parallelism.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I second @D.W.'s concern. With $p$ processors you can never get (asymptotic) speedup larger than $p$, so (alleged) exponential hardness can't be mitigated, that much is clear (?).

Comment: Just an important note: NP-hardness is not a property of an algorithm.